# Byobu using regular .bash_profile

Tags: terminal

I'm getting started with Byobu. I would like it to essentially act just like my regular shell (I use the bash-it framework), using my `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`, but with the perks of the Byobu interface.

However, when I start up a terminal session with Byobu, I have to manually source `.bash_profile` to get my environment set up as usual. Is there a config setting or a file to modify to set this on the start of Byobu?

EDIT: AskUbuntu and Unix&Linux have a tag for `byobu`. If someone with high enough reputation comes across this, please edit this post to create and include that tag.

Comment: How do you start Byobu also first sentence says .bashrc and .bash_profile second only says the latter.

Comment: @Mark I've started it using `byobu` in the terminal and via a new terminal after enabling it as the default with `byobu-enable`.

Comment: How does the terminal run byobu in the second case. I note that byobu docs a blocked by my web settings - which ios bas as they are shouid just be html pages so using other sites would make me worry re this app.  worrying. but the main page does list byobu-config

Comment: @Mark Please revise your comments for grammar errors before posting; I'm not quite sure what you're saying after the first sentence. Regarding the first sentence, the second method has the same behavior as executing `byobu` in a regular terminal. In both instances, many of the environment variables are the same but with the difference of a few variables' contents -- though commands such as aliases only work after `source ~/.bash_profile`. Also, regarding your first comment: the second sentence only says `.bash_profile` because it's standard procedure to `source ~/.bashrc` from `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Sorry - basically I can't read the byobu docs as they are filtered because they are youtube or on a third party site which makes me worried by the source of the docs which should be plain HTML so I am not going to risk reading them. But I do see a command byobu-config which might be of interest.

Comment: @Mark the docs at linux.die.net are HTML from what I see. I asked on here because I couldn't find anything in the man pages. However, I found a workaround using the idea presented here: https://superuser.com/a/1350388/693732. I like to use bash-it for my shell, but since my `.bash_profile` launches byobu due to the`byobu-enable` command, the terminal ends up in an infinite loop. Instead, I copied the bash-it source line from my `.bash_profile` to the bashrc that `~/.byobu/prompt` points to. If anyone has a more official method to do this please post it as an answer.

Comment: Your not going to make match progress in the world of computers if you do not consult the internet.  I assume you got a mac.  macOS is very secure. If you still worried, get an ipad to do you surfing.  Set up a linux distro in the free virtual box for you web surfing.

Comment: @historystamp is that directed towards @Mark?

Comment: Yes but when uMatrix shows a blocked box for simple html on a doc page at byobu/org it suggests the authors don't want to help. I am not going to waste time on seeing why it is not a simple html link element.

Comment: @Mark It's probably because you have uMatrix setup to block iframes and byobu.org uses an iframe to point to manpages.ubuntu.com